# Error during the Implementation of Calculator using javaswing

Tags: java, swing, calculator

I am creating a calculator using Java Swing. When I implement the actionListener to any button in a class called buttonclick, it gives me an error "illegal start of expression". What should I do?

```
public class Frame extends JFrame
{
    public Frame ()
    {
        JButton zero = new JButton ("0");
        written = new JTextArea ();

        private class buttonclick implements ActionListener 
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                Object x = e.getSource();
                if (x == zero)
                    written.setText(written.getText().concat("0"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: yeah, I moved the function actionPerformed to the Frame class and made this class implements ActionListener instead of creating a new class inside the frame class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are defining a `private` local class in `Frame()` constructor, `private` modifier can't be used in methods